# How to make actionbarsherlock tabs open listviews instead of fragments

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I want to create a feed like the one in the facebook app, and I want to have actionbarsherlock navigation tabs that will be used to filter the feed - a tab for people, a tab for places and a tab for items.

Right now I've set it up so that each tab opens up a fragment. How can I make them open up a list view instead?

```
    ActionBar.Tab itemsFeedTab = actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab peopleFeedTab = actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab placesFeedTab = actionBar.newTab();

    Fragment itemsFeedFragment = new FeedItems();
    Fragment peopleFeedFragment = new FeedPeople();
    Fragment placesFeedFragment = new FeedPlaces();

    itemsFeedTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(itemsFeedFragment));
    peopleFeedTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(peopleFeedFragment));
    placesFeedTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(placesFeedFragment));

    actionBar.addTab(itemsFeedTab, 0, true);
    actionBar.addTab(peopleFeedTab, 1, false);
    actionBar.addTab(placesFeedTab, 2, false);


class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.replace(R.id.home, fragment);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fragments contain only `ListView`s then its better to use `ListFragment`

Comment: is that what they are using at facebook?

Comment: so my code will remain as is, I just use ListFragment within my Fragments?

Comment: most of the parts yes.. you can refer to [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listactivity) tutorial here for more info

Comment: replace `ListFragment` with `SherlockListFragment`

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is hidden in your question , you are trying to open `ListView` instead of `Fragment`.

Why don't you open a `ListFragment` and you are done.